# Extending a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open disc.

Is there a function $$ f \in {\mathcal H}(\mathop D ) \cap C(\overline{D}), $$ such that, 
$\,\,f \notin {\mathcal H}(V)$,
for every open set $V \supset \overline{D}\,$?

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such function is
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n+1}z^{2^n+1}.
$$
The derivative of this function 
$$
h(z)=f'(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nz^{2^n},
$$
is Hardy's power series, which has the property that, it is holomorphic in $D$,
bounded in $\overline{D}$, but no limit
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0}h(z),
$$
for $|z_0|=1$ exists. Hence its anti-derivative extends continuously to $\overline{D}$, but it can not be analytic outside of $\overline{D}$, as its derivative would not be analytic at any point of $\partial D$.

Comment: I was reading your answer on my question until you deleted it!

Answer (score 1):

What you really mean is to ask for an $f$ defined on the closed disk that *cannot be extended* to an open set that contain the disk. Otherwise you could just define its values outside the disk to be deliberately discontinuous.

---

For the unit disc, try $f(z)=\sqrt{z+1}$, choosing some consistent branch of the square root.